# (Win32 API) Hovering a menu item causes VS to throw an exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, winapi

I use Visual Studio 2022 Community (17.1.3) with C++ 17

It was a pain to manage menus from the raw *Win32 API*, but with the help of the *OOP*, I have successfully encapsulated all functions related to menus, so I don't need to care anymore about indexes if I want to do something with one of the items inside a menu.

However, when the mouse cursor hits an item, VS throws the following exception:

```
wil::ResultException at memory location 0x[Address].
[Rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
```

The app can still run (it doesn't crash, the exception is actually in the output window of VS!)
`GetLastError()` at the end of the execution returns 0. I can also retrieve what item has been clicked by the user with `WM_COMMAND`, and it works well.

I don't know whether it's normal or not, but I also tried to compile the template project and another project I've done in the past with the Win32 API, and guess what, the same happens. Hence I think it's not a specific problem related to my code *(although I don't have much experience in C++, considering it's been only two years since I started to learn it)*, but a problem of the IDE itself.

**main.cpp**

```
// ---------- main.cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, 
LPARAM lParam);

// Globals
HINSTANCE inst;
HWND mainWnd;
HMENU menuBar;
HMENU subMenu1;
HMENU subMenu2;

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE p_hInst, HINSTANCE p_hPrevInst, LPWSTR p_lpszArgs, int p_nCmdShow) 
{
    inst = p_hInst;

    // register the main window class
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { 0 };
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcex.hInstance = inst;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"Menus";

    if (!RegisterClassExW(&wcex)) 
    {
        // handle error
    }

    mainWnd = CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"Menus", L"Using menus", 
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, inst, NULL);

    if (NULL == mainWnd) 
    {
        // Handle error
    }
    ShowWindow(mainWnd, p_nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(mainWnd);

    // Create a message structure and start the main loop
    MSG message;

    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, NULL, NULL)) 
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    return (int)message.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    switch (uMsg) 
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        // Create and set the menu
        menuBar = CreateMenu();
        subMenu1 = CreatePopupMenu();
        subMenu2 = CreatePopupMenu();

        AppendMenu(subMenu1, MF_STRING, ID_ITM1, L"Item 01");
        AppendMenu(subMenu1, MF_STRING, ID_ITM2, L"Item 02");
        AppendMenu(subMenu1, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
        AppendMenu(subMenu1, MF_STRING, ID_ITMCLOSE, L"Close");

        AppendMenu(subMenu2, MF_STRING, ID_ITMABOUT, L"About...");

        AppendMenu(menuBar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)subMenu1, L"Menu");
        AppendMenu(menuBar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)subMenu2, L"Help");

        SetMenu(hWnd, menuBar);
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case ID_ITMABOUT:
            MessageBox(mainWnd, L"Using menus -- Just an example for Stack Overflow", L"About...", MB_OK);
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(GetLastError());

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**resource.h**

```
#pragma once

#define ID_ITM1      5000
#define ID_ITM2      5100
#define ID_ITM3      5200
#define ID_ITM4      5300
#define ID_ITMCLOSE  5400
#define ID_ITMABOUT  5500

/* -------------------------------------------------------------
(Don't forget to add an empty line to avoid the "unexpected 
end of line error of VS if you don't use the integrated resource 
editor.") 
------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

This sample contains the minimum code to create an empty window and assign it a menu.

If you highlight one of the items or click the "About" item and look at the Output window of VS, exceptions will start to throw without any reason, but the app will continue to run fine.
Please, note that it will take some seconds, be patient.
[My Visual Studio Output Window looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWCz9.png).

**Edit:**

- clearer explanations about the problem.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Chances are that there actually is a bug in your code, but we cannot see it.

Comment: It is not a crash, just a debugger notification.  WIL is an acronym for the [Windows Implementation Library](https://github.com/microsoft/wil).  Aptly named, Microsoft uses it internally to implement Win10+ plumbing.  And yes, that C++ code does use exceptions, if one is tripped then you'll see that back when you debug your own code.  Something did go wrong, but there isn't anything you can do about it and tends to have no consequences.  You can report it at the github site.

Comment: Thanks for your response and your explanation! As long as it hasn't any consequences, it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's indeed a problem with menus in VS2022 (17.1.4, std/C++17 flag).
When I compile the code above (which does not contain any bugs), it throws the `wil::ResultException` in my output window, but the program itself continues to run fine.

[image: My Output window]

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted to know.
I don't know why I have two downvotes since I didn't do anything wrong. If something is missing or incomplete, I will edit the post to make sure everyone can understand the problem, don't be shy :)
Anyway, thanks for your response. I'll try to compile this code in older versions of VS and Code::Block to confirm that it is not related to the current VS but the win32 API itself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question asked. If you need to confirm the observed behavior, leave a comment.